# How to access current selection on a Combobox from a list

Tags: python, list, tkinter, combobox

I have a bunch of combo boxes  that I am using in a window. There is too many to define each one separately, so I have used a function to create them. I have also added them to a list, so that I can later recall them. However when I use the .get() on one of the instances in the list, the value that I get is the value that I set it to. Therefore If I was to select a different value in the combo box, and then call the same .get(), It would output the same value as before, because it has not updated in the list. How can I get it to update so that whenever I call .get() onto one of the values in the list, it gives me the latest value. Here is some example code to give a better idea.

```
alterBox = ttk.Combobox(root, values = ("1", "2", "3"))     
alterBox.config(height = 7, width =7)
alterBox.set("1")
alterBox.place(x=10, y=10)
list.append(alterBox)
```

when I call `print((list[0]).get())` I receive "1", however when I choose 2 in the drop down, and then call `print((list[0].get())` I receive "1".

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: there is function `list()` so don't use name `list` because it overwrites function.

Comment: where do you use `list[0]).get()` ? Maybe you use it before you select element.

Comment: example: [combobox get selection](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/blob/master/tkinter/combobox-get-selection/main.py)